# How to properly spell the slang “Hé bé”?

Tags: orthographe, oral, argot

Whilst living in France, I used 'Hé bé' a lot, although, I have never written it. I was just wondering how the French would spell it?

Comment: I'd like to add in that I lived in the Dordogne, so it may well be relative to their own slang words/spelling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'un point de vue étymologique, *eh/hé bien* correspond exactement à ce qu'on cherche à écrire. Toutefois, si on cherche à mettre l'accent sur la prononciation plus régionale, il n'y a rien de mal à écrire *hé bé*, au même titre qu'on écrit (dans le cas de prononciation familière) *y'a qu'à* (ou même *yaka*), *pô* (Dans *Titeuf*, par exemple, si ma mémoire est bonne) ou encore *chuis*.

Comment: _hé bé_ n'est pas du tout argotique. C'est juste un régionalisme méridional, au même titre que _boudu_ (sauf que le premier vient du français alors que le second vient de l'occitan).

Comment: Ah, pardon. Étant québécois, je n'ai pas beaucoup d'expérience avec les accents régionaux français. Je vais modifier ma réponse.

Comment: Notice that *eh bien* is [by far](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eh+bien%2Ch%C3%A9+bien&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19) the dominant variant.

Comment: Interesting.  What does this slang word mean and how is it used exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Je l'écrirais [eh bien](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/eh%20bien) sauf dans les contextes où on cherche absolument à marquer les variations de prononciations, alors « eh bin » est plus proche de ce que je dis que « eh bé », mais j'imagine sans mal des variations.

Note, pour moi « eh » et « hé » sont deux orthographes admissibles du même mot, certains cherchent à faire une nuance entre les deux (parfois même une différence de prononciation, [e] ou [ɛ]).  Je n'ai jamais compris quel était exactement la nuance, et j'ai l'impression que la prononciation [e] ou [ɛ] dépend plus du locuteur que d'une nuance sous-jacente.